# How to get a VPN for ubuntu?

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I saw a thing called VPN connections under the Internet button at the top of my screen.
[image: VPN]

So I would like more info on this, and possibly instructions on how to set one up. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

VPN as a client [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient)

Setting up an OpenVPN server [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNServer)

VPN setup in Ubuntu – General introduction [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN)

How to set up an SSH VPN. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN)

How to set up a VPN server on Ubuntu [here](http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/02/09/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-ubuntu/)