# How to setup an intranet in ubuntu using wifi?

Tags: 12.04, vpn, intranet

I want to set up a VPN on my laptop but I don't know what and how to set it. My requirements are :

- Intranet with a customizable list of shared folders.
- Intranet outsourced via computer wifi.
- Possibly assigning individual private IP addresses to all connected.
- Facility to share internet (if hassel free).

Can I do this using Gnome Network Manager or do I need another program? I'll be happy even if I get one folder to share for the time being and no internet if I could only outsource one file/folder.

Comment: good information on how to set up in uBuntu 16 is provided in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-intranet-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  The answer in this question points to a few methods to get set up.

[How to get a VPN for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145330/how-to-get-a-vpn-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you look at a wrapper tool like http://www.zentyal.com which allows easy configuration of tools/services that you need including internet sharing ;)

Comment: The company is professional. I need open source or freeware as it is for sake of studying only. Thanks anyway.